# Open Source (Linux-) Server monitoring Software with lightweight footprint

Tags: linux, monitoring, open-source, lightweight

What OSS monitoring soltions are there? I know only nagios & cacti.

Are there any real live performance monitoring tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look on Monit.

http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.zabbix.com

It's not as fully featured as Nagios but its improving pretty rapidly. Its quite lite weight both in terms of server load for output and the collectors too.

Comment: If you do have the spare cpu & memory consider ZenOss Core http://zenoss.org - after you get used to its user interface its really nice to use and has a lot of very cool features [like different levels of user accounts, reports etc] that so far I've only seen available in commercial apps.

Comment: Zenoss Core is great (my company uses it), but it's not lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

for trend tracking - [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/). you can use it as well as source of alerts for [nagios](http://nagios.org).